# Deserialize an object with property of abstract type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

I have a case where I need to deserialize a json file but one property differs a little in some cases. Here is an example:

```
[
    {
        "NameProperty": "ex1",
        "OtherProperty":"example",
        "DifferentProperty": "here is a string value"
    },
    {
        "NameProperty": "ex1",
        "OtherProperty":"example",
        "DifferentProperty": ["here", "is", "an" "array"]
    },
    {
        "NameProperty": "ex1",
        "OtherProperty":"example",
        "DifferentProperty": 234 //number
    }
]
```

And here are models for such json:

abstract class PropertyBase
    {
    }

```
class StringProperty : PropertyBase
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
class ArrayProperty : PropertyBase
{
    public IList<string> Value { get; set; }
}
class NumberProperty : PropertyBase
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}


class ExampleModel
{
    public string NameProperty { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public PropertyBase DifferentProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to pass a list of the objects to the asp.net core a controller function e.g.:

```
public IActionResult ExampleFunction([FromBody] List<ExampleModel> request){ }
```

And here is a problem because I know how to deserialize list of derived classes but I don't know how to deserialize an object with property of abstract type. I want to write a JsonConvert class which will be passed to asp.net mvc config.

Comment: because abstract class not instantiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

```
public class ExampleModelConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        var name = token["NameProperty"].ToString();
        PropertyBase prop = null;
        // for example, it is up to you how you
        // create an instance of PropertyBase
        switch (name)
        {
            case "string" : prop = new StringProperty();
                break;
            case "number" : prop = new NumberProperty();
                break;
            case "array" : prop = new ArrayProperty();
                break;
        }

        var ex = new ExampleModel
        {
            DifferentProperty = prop
        };
        serializer.Populate(reader, ex);
        return ex;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ExampleModel) == objectType;
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyConverter))]
class ExampleModel
{
    public string NameProperty { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public PropertyBase DifferentProperty { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleModel>(jsonData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! :) I was on track but you enlighted me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just skip the entire PropertyBase thing, why not just create a resolver for your ExampleModel that does something like this:

```
class ExampleModel
{
    public string NameProperty { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public object DifferentProperty { get; set; }

    public string DifferentPropertyString { get; set; }
    public string[] DifferentPropertyStringArray { get; set; }
    public int DifferentPropertyInt { get; set; }

    private void ResolveDifferentProperty()
    {
        // Try to resolve the DifferentProperty property with a converter or 
        //something similar into one of your three specific "DifferentProperty"'s?
    }
}

class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleModel>(jsonData);
        model.ResolveDifferentProperty();
    }
}
```

In order to know which property has been resolved into, maybe let the ExampleModel contain a property of DifferentPropertyEnum or something so you know which property has been populated from the resolving. You get the idea.

Also, remember that there will be no way for you to know what kind of property this really is by compile time. You can not access it with the *var* keyword or anything like that, so you'd have to switch on this property a lot if you're gonna use it a lot.

You can bypass this, of course, by making that DifferentProperty object a dynamic (literally with the *dynamic* keyword). This will not generate compiler warnings, but it will crash runtime if you are not careful with it. It is considered more unsafe, of course, but let's say that your controller only wants to store this in a varchar database field or something, then I would probably go with the dynamic.